# How to validate required bootstrap date field in angularjs using ng-required

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am unable to validate required bootstrap date field in angularjs using ng-required. Here is my code.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label class="control-label col-md-4" style="text-align: left;" for="Date">Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class='input-group date' id='assignWODate'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="woAssignedDate" bs-datepicker ng-required="woAssignedDate" ng-readonly="true" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above issue by including a  forceParse: false attribute in my script tag and making it readonly field. No need for any other validation.

```
     $('#assignWODate').datepicker({
            autoclose:true,
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate: dt,
            forceParse: false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do validation ng-required while it is readonly
see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/22868/)

```
  <form>
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" style="text-align: left;" for="Date">Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class='input-group date' id='assignWODate'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="woAssignedDate" bs-datepicker ng-required="woAssignedDateIsRequired"   />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: Your code will work on submit. i want to fire a validation message on blur or focus out of the date field. How can i achieve the same.